# rast() can´t open Rasterbrick files anymore

Tags: r, raster

Out of a sudden rast() in terra tells me that:

```
Stack_evi <- rast(EVI_corrected)
global_evi<-global(Stack_evi,"mean",weights=NULL, na.rm=TRUE )

evi_corrected.grd' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)
```

although I was able to do the exact same thing hours ago just fine.

EVI_corrected is a .grd file that i have imported as a Ratserbrick.

I don´t think it is a problem with my code as it worked just fine hours ago.

Comment: One option may be update your `terra` and `raster` package to the latest version.

Comment: updating the packages might help as @UseR10085 suggested. Have yiou checked the other questions about the ```(GDAL error 4)``` ? and the answers that fixed those cannot read problems?